# What is the best practice between using "import module" and "from module import *" in python? Which usage is more efficient and why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have seen both the codes used interchangeably in python.

```
Import module
```

Or

```
From module import *
```

What is the difference between above 2 codes? What does it signify? What is the best practice in terms of coding efficiency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import math
print math.pi
```

Or

```
from math import *
print pi
```

Answer (score 3):

`import module` imports one object, the module. You can access members of that module via dot notation (eg: `module.someFunc()`).

`from module import *` imports everything that the module exports. It does *not* import the module, so you can't use dot notation. For example, you can do `myFunc()` but not `module.myFunc()`.

Generally speaking, `from module import *` is discouraged because it pollutes the namespace. [PEP8 has a section on imports](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) worth reading. Here's an excerpt:

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools.